# Нужно чтобы c dlink в DHCPACK не прихоила опция domain

Tags: macos, dns, macbook, d-link

Всем привет!
У меня на маке меняется hostname при подключении к wifi. Роутер Dlink, MacBook Pro, macOS Monterey. В поддержке у провайдера ничем помочь не могут. Помогите пожалуйста.

[image: Скрин из терминала]

[image: Скрин настроек DNS на Mac]

Как это исправить?

Comment: в настройках роутера проверьте Local Domain Name и поменяйте на local, возможно тогда будет приходить от DHCP имя с *.local

Comment: Почему-то такого нигде нет...

Comment: Все заработало. Проблема была в нерабочем скрипте для работы интернета из под внутреннего впн